# How to make a selenium based automation app for android?

Tags: python, android, selenium, automation, appium

Ok so this is what i want to do, i have made a very simple script on Appium that simply opens an app inside my phone and leaves a comment or likes a post automatically.

It works but now i want to convert all of this automation code to a .apk, so i can install it on my phone and execute that automation task on my phone without pc.

But for some reason it crashes on phone if i import appium or selenium on the top of code, is it possible to do something like that or is selenium only limited to be used on pc, is there any alternate.

Even if somehow i manage to make it work on phone i will still need a live appium server and a way to get adb devices id inside phone but that is for later.

Please help, if there is any alternate on any programming language.
There is a app on play store called Tasker which does similar stuff but i don't think it can interact with a phone like selenium does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pack it in your phone,
The best way to achieve this is to use `Java + Selenium + Appium`.

If you really want to use python.
I think you should learn about python `kivy` module.
But it maybe has many limitations.It is not a good idea.

Also,I have another way to do something about automation,`AutoJS` is a app which can be used in your phone but you should learn about `Javascript`.

Comment: yes i did it on kivy, still no go but yes maybe i should try it on java thanks for suggestion.